# select all values of one column from datagridview to a cell in other datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi everyone please I want you're help if it's possible :

In the first Form I have a `DataGridView` and `TextBoxes` that send data to another `DataGridView` in the second form when I click the button **Télécharger PDF** without selecting rows it select all automatically:

- The problem is that I want to add all value of the first column for example "Arduino + scotch" in cell of the second `DataGridView`.
- I think it will be the same way for the total I want to add the Sum in one cell of the form2.

[image: Form1]

[image: Form2]

**Form1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Form2 f2 = new Form2();

            string firstcol = textBox3.Text;
            string secondcol = textBox1.Text;
            string thirdtcol = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString();
            string fourcol = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].ToString();

   //thirdcole and fourcol are not working even for 1 row

            string[] rows = { firstcol, secondcol, thirdtcol, fourcol };

            f2.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows);

            f2.Show();

            this.Hide();
        
    }
```

**Form2 :**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void A_commande_etat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So basically, all string values in the Article column in Form1 should be concatenated and added to a single string value and placed in a cell in Form2? The same applies for the values in the total column values in Form1?

Comment: yes sir exactly, and in each button click we create an other row in Form2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Form2` add a method that takes the `dataGridView1` from `Form1` and loops through the deciered columns and creates the wanted concatenated/summed values and then add it as a new row for the `dataGridView` in `Form2`.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 f2; //Don't create a new f2 object each time button is pressed
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            f2 = new Form2();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f2.Show();
            //Send the datagridview of Form1 to Form 2, let Form2 do all the logic
            f2.loadColumns(this.dataGridView1); 
        }
    }
```

**Form2**

```
using System.Text;

public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
      
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public  void loadColumns(DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            StringBuilder buildArticleString = new StringBuilder();

            int articleColIndex = 0; //Your article col index in Form1
            int totalColIndex = 4; //Your total col index in Form1
            int totalSum = 0;
            
            foreach(DataGridViewRow currentRow in dataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (currentRow.Cells[articleColIndex].Value == null || currentRow.Cells[totalColIndex].Value == null)
                    continue;

                //Retrive cell value at article column for current row, append to stringbuilder
                buildArticleString.Append(currentRow.Cells[articleColIndex].Value.ToString());
                buildArticleString.Append(" + ");


                int currentTotalValue = 0;
                //Checks if value in cell can be converted to int, skips if not
                if (Int32.TryParse(currentRow.Cells[totalColIndex].Value.ToString(), out currentTotalValue))
                {
                    totalSum += currentTotalValue;
                }
            }

            buildArticleString.Remove(buildArticleString.Length - 3, 3); //Remove trailing " + ";

            //Make sure this matches your columns in Form2
            string[] rowValues = new string[] {"", "", buildArticleString.ToString(), totalSum.ToString(), "", "" }; 
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowValues); //Add new row to Form2
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir it works you really helped me too much, just one issue please: string firstcol = textBox3.Text;  and string secondcol = textBox1.Text; how can i add it to fill column 1 and 2 of DGV form2 and thank you againe for you're help, i'm a beginner

Comment: @walid Do you want to add text from the textboxes to the first 2 cells when the user presses  button1?

Comment: If that is the case you should be able to just add it to the line `string[] rowValues = new string[] {"", "", buildArticleString.ToString(), totalSum.ToString(), "", "" }; ` and change it to `string[] rowValues = new string[] {textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text, buildArticleString.ToString(), totalSum.ToString(), "", "" }; `